# layout:false not working in express.js 3?

Tags: express, pug

i try to skip rendering the layout when rendering a view in express.js. I use jade as my template language. the code i use:

```
res.render("show", { job: data, layout: false });
```

any advice? it keeps rendering the layout....

thanks

Comment: layout has been removed from express 3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think that's the default now.

Otherwise try:

```
app.set('view options', {
    layout: false
});
```